# Provisioning profile doesn't include the currently selected device error

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild, visual-studio-mac

I was debugging iPad app in my iPad and everything was working fine. Then I reset the iPad and when I debug the app, it started giving error related to provisioning profile. It seemed the UID of iPad in Apple developer account got greyed out. It was enabled and new provisioning profile was generated but still I am getting the `Provisioning profile doesn't include the currently selected device` error. Both Visual Studio for Mac and Xcode have the same issue. May I know if any of you has faced similar issues and if so, how were you able to fix?

Comment: Remove provision from your system and download again and install and check again

Comment: I tried that as well. Now I noticed the iPad OS 13.6 I have is not supported with Xcode 11.5. That could be one of the reason. So, I am downloading the Xcode 11.6. Once Xcode is ready, we need to see.

Answer (score 1):

If you try all of that and nothing works ensure any iOS device or a physical phone is selected and not my mac.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the device UID in Apple developer account, it worked with updated provisioning profile.